# Can Not Insert Record with NULL Value for Constrained PK (Auto-Increment) Column

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, innodb

I have two tables, let's call them `charts` and `charts_tree`. The `charts_tree.idDir` (auto-increment, integer) column is constrained to `charts.chart_tree_dir`. Both tables are InnoDB based.

Now I am trying to insert a row in `charts_tree` with `null` value for `idDir` (due to its auto-increment nature), but I am getting a foreign constrain fails error message on this column. How is this possible, considering that both tables are blank initially and there are no interconnected columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the foreign key constraint on the idDir column and references the chart_tree_dir column ?
That's what I understood from what you said ; if that's the case, when you try to insert a row in charts_tree, the auto_incremented value generated by mysql is not present in charts at the moment of creation (since both tables are blank), thus the foreign key failing.
It should be the other way around I think.